# How to check JobStatus for scheduled sends with Salesforce Data Extensions

Tags: marketing-cloud, email, query, dataextensions

When scheduling the email with normal data extension, we will be able to see the status of email whether it's paused or scheduled. However, we can't see/check the status of email scheduled with salesforce data extensions.

I would like to know if there's any data view that we can use to run query and check the status?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Email Studio > Interactions > Salesforce Sends